# How to display a dialog box when clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to display a dialog box by clicking on the button in my JSP page. 
Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
            <form action="/HabilitationFaite" method="POST">
                ...
                ...
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="alerte_habilitation('Test!')">Envoyer</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function alerte_habilitation( msg ){
                var popup = $("<div></div>");
                $(popup).append('<img src="img/bigWarning.png" 
                class="dialog-image">');
                $(popup).append('<span class="dialog-msg">'+msg+'</span>');

                var popupConf = { 
                        autoOpen  : true,
                        resizable : false,
                        draggable : false,
                        width     : 500,
                        title     : "Attention",
                        modal     : true,
                        buttons   : {
                            "OK": function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    };

                $(popup).dialog( popupConf );
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code does not display the dialog box and i don't find a solution.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: didn't you forget to include some jquery/bootstrap script/css file. It looks, like you are using dialog feature from some framework, what is not loaded.

Comment: you should have some error in console because of that

Comment: @EduardVoid I don't have error. The function is used in another JSP page and it works. Idon't know why it doesn't work here. I'm a beginner with JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Finally, like as he said EduardVoid, i forget to include some jquery/bootstrap :

```
        <script src="/js/lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/lib/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Bootstrap Popover**. 
Bootstrap has many things ready for you, because if you write stuff on your  own you might come up with problems already solved in popular libraries/frameworks. If you do not want to load the whole framework, bootstrap lets you load only the modules you need.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

Comment: But the function is used in another JSP page and it works. Idon't know why it doesn't work here.

Comment: Is the code exactly the same in the other page? For example here i see a double declaration of the $() jquery object:
var popup = $("<div></div>");
                $(popup).append('<img src="img/bigWarning.png" 
                class="dialog-image">');

Comment: I make an answer. I forget to include jquery/bootstrap